# Wordpress Install 404 Error (Cannot view login in browser)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am installing Wordpress for the first time so please bear with me. I have installed the LAMP stack and have verified that Apache is running, Mysql is working, and that PHP is installed. However when I follow tutorials to install Wordpress I get to the end and I'm asked to type in my server address or my IP. I have typed in localhost and it takes me to the Apache welcome page. I have typed in localhost/wordpressfiles/wordpress, localhost/wordpress, localhost/wordpress/install.php, and various other combinations and still get this 404 Error:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /wordpressfiles/wordpress/wp-admin on this server. Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

***Here is my file hierarchy which gets me to my install.php file:
/home/dylan/wordpressfiles/wordpress/wp-admin ***

I am not sure what I'm missing here. Here is a link to the tutorial I followed (although I have sought out others to help me with no luck thus far) [Click Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check if you set the correct owner and priviledge for the folder.

Comment: First of all, please chek your virtual host settings. I've noticed that you in ubuntu so you need to run `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` in command line interface. You are looking for line `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` or something similar. Check that this line are same as you wordpress path `/home/dylan/wordpressfiles/wordpress`. Next, like in Kris comment, check that www-data user which is using by apache have previleges for `home/dylan/wordpressfiles/wordpress` folder.

Comment: Also, check `Directory` section in your virtual host config. It should looks like `<Directory /home/dylan/wordpressfiles/wordpress>` and contains needed options. My dev config is like follow `Allow from all`. Please check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/marvin255/b13084a251e0b568aab3263189644d9f) for example.

Comment: ok so what I'm seeing is that I have my files set up like this /home/dylan/wordpressfiles/wordpress/htaccess However the .hataccess folder is empty. I think that may be the problem seeing as how it deals with security and permissions from what I gather. Am I correct in this assumption? If so what is supposed to go into the .htaccess file? I guess I missed that part of the tutorials :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some digging I found that the wordpress files were not in the proper directory. I moved the wordpress install files into the directory /var/www/html. Now I'm up an running.